# SharePoint Custom NewForm and EditForm Redirect to Workflow Initiation Page

Tags: designer-workflow, url, redirect

I need assistance with redirecting my custom newform.aspx and editform.aspx to a custom sharepoint designer workflow initiation page. I've been testing form action buttons in both new and edit form with commit, and then navigate to page, but I can't get it to work with passing the @ItemId or @ID parameter. I know the newform will be a little more challenging since the ID isn't created until after the item is created. Any information how to get these form redirects working is greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks!

Comment: try this: http://sprider.org/2012/10/31/redirecting-spd-newform-aspx-to-other-pages-with-the-current-item-id-as-query-string/

Comment: Additonal information on this questions would be great!!